# Event log error for Microsoft-Windows-Perflib ID 1008

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-event-log

I started seeing the following error in my Windows Server 2012 event application logs somewhat recently, possibly after installing some Windows updates.

```
Log Name:         Application
Source:           Microsoft-Windows-Perflib
Date:             2018/11/11 14:02:21
Event ID:         1008
Task Category:    None
Level:            Error
Keyword:          Classic
Explanation:
The Open Procedure for service Remote Access in DLL "C:Windows\System32\rasctrs.dll" failed. 
Performance data for this service will not be available. 
The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code
Event XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Perflib" Guid="{13B197BD-7CEE-4B4E-8DD0-59314CE374CE}" EventSourceName="Perflib" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">1008</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-11-11T05:02:21.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>35760</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>COMP1.TEST.LOCAL</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <UserData>
    <EventXML xmlns="Perflib">
      <param1>RemoteAccess</param1>
      <param2>C:\Windows\System32\rasctrs.dll</param2>
      <binaryDataSize>8</binaryDataSize>
      <binaryData>0200000000000000</binaryData>
    </EventXML>
  </UserData>
</Event>
```

There is also a similar error for the BITS (bitsperf.dll) service.

I want to get rid of this error and have tried the entering the following commands (which are commonly mentioned in other forums and websites). However, they do not seem to have any effect.

```
C:\Windows\system32\lodctr.exe /R
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lodctr.exe /R
C:\Windows\System32\wbem\winmgmt.exe /RESYNCPERF
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\winmgmt.exe /RESYNCPERF
lodctr /T:TermService
```

In the registry I've also checked the read permissions in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ but they are the same as the other services.

I've also seen recommendations that people disable the performance counters for the above services. But to me this feels like it isn't really solving the error insofar as it is hiding it?

I should also mention that the server is in a closed environment (no internet access).

Is there anything else I can do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Can you provide the full event log information so we can see the data section?

Comment: @HelpingHand It looks like the entire event message is that which I posted initially. There is no further information.

Comment: Can you right click on the event and choose - Copy - Copy details as text and paste that.  Or at least the data section as that's what it is referring to in the message.

Comment: @HelpingHand Okay, I see what you mean. The event message is not in English so I guess I'll try to translate the non-English parts.

Comment: Maybe this tool could be of use: https://web.archive.org/web/20160126031424/http://download.microsoft.com/download/win2000platform/exctrlst/1.00.0.1/nt5/en-us/exctrlst_setup.exe

Answer (score 1):

For those who're searching how to correctly resolve BITS performance counter error 1008 without rebuilding everything as shown above, here we go (in Admin command prompt):

```
FOR /R C:\Windows\INF\bits\ %I IN (*bitsctrs.ini) DO lodctr /r %I
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1035945/how-to-use-lodctr-to-resolve-event-id-1008-or-3009)